# Linearly independence and span

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, independence

Let $v_1$, $v_2$, $\cdots$, $v_m$ $\in$ V are linearly independent and assume $v_1$, $v_2$, $\cdots$, $v_m$ do not span. I know "do not span" means not all the vectors in V are in span( $v_1$, $v_2$, $\cdots$, $v_m$).

My question is: What do they span?

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

When we define the span of the vectors of the set  $S:=\{v_1,...,v_m\}$ we define the next set:

$$
span(S):=\{\sum_{i=1}^m{\lambda_i·v_i} : \lambda_i \in \mathbb{K}\} 
$$

where $\mathbb{K}$ is the field of the vectorial space.

This is, all the vectors of the vectorial space that can be expressed as a linear combination of  the vectors of the set $S$

I suppose that when it says that "they don't span V" they want to say that not all vectors of the subvectorial space $(V,\mathbb{K})$ can be expressed as a linear combination of the $\{v_i\}_{i=1...m}$ vectors.

For example, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the vector $(0,1)$ don't generate all the vectorial space but $\{(0,1),(1,0)\}$ generate all $\mathbb{R^2}$

because

$(\lambda,\delta)=\lambda(1,0)+\delta·(0,1) \forall \lambda,\delta \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I was required to show that there exists a $v_{m+1}$ $\in$ V such that {$v_1$, $v_2$, $\cdots$, $v_m$, $v_{m+1}$} is a linearly independent set. So I guess the vectors should span something so that I can make the proof.

Comment: Well, if you know that not all vectors of V can be expressed as linear combination of $v_i$ you can take one of them and this vector will be linearly independent with the $v_i$ vectors, (if not, all vectors of V could be expressed as a linear combination of $v_i$ and this is a contradiction).